# how body parser works in node js

Tags: node.js, angular, express, body-parser

I know that body parser is used to extract data, but how this works. I'm sending `JSON.stringify(data)` from my angular 2 view but in my node js + express rest API I don't need to use `JSON.parse(req.body)` to use the data, please explain to me how this works exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body-parser module runs `JSON.parse` on the request body automatically when using the json mode (docs [here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions)), as long as the Content-Type header of the incoming request matches the mode used (application/json in this example).

See the source [here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/master/lib/types/json.js) for how body-parser actually does it.

Comment: That is correct expect he mentioned using JSON.stringify meanning he would be using the text body parser of course https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparsertextoptions

Comment: @RLaaa I'm not sure that's the case. POSTed data always needs to be stringified before the request happens. I suspect he's sending application/json and using the json mode in body parser, and that's why he doesn't need to do another parse after the fact.